# How to do join operation on service side in WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, join, wcf-data-services

I know that "join" is not supported on client side with WCF DS thats why i decided to add a method on server side to do the "join" and return the result as custom type object. 
Service looks like this:

```
 public class CWcfDataService : DataService<CEntities>
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.RegisterKnownType(typeof(CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED));
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED> GetCASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDEDByDocId(int docId)
        {
            CEntities context = new CEntities();
            return (from c in context.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY
                    join a in context.USRs on c.CREATOR_ID equals a.USRID
                    select new CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED()
                    {
                        CASE_STAGE_ID = c.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_ID,
                        CASE_STAGE_NAME = c.CASE_STAGE_NAME,
                        CREATE_DATE = c.CREATE_DATE,
                        CREATOR_ID = c.CREATOR_ID,
                        DOC_ID = c.DOC_ID,
                        LAST_VARIANT_DOCUMENT_ID = c.LAST_VARIANT_DOCUEMENT_ID,
                        CREATOR_FULLNAME = a.FULLNAME
                    });
        }    
    }
```

And custom class is:

```
   [DataServiceKey("CASE_STAGE_ID")]
    public class CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED
    {
        public int CASE_STAGE_ID { get; set; }
        public int DOC_ID { get; set; }
        public string CASE_STAGE_NAME { get; set; }
        public int? LAST_VARIANT_DOCUMENT_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CREATE_DATE { get; set; }
        public int? CREATOR_ID { get; set; }
        public string CREATOR_FULLNAME { get; set; }
    }
```

When i try to update service reference in Visual Studio i constantly get error:

> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Unable to load metadata
>   for return type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED]'
>   of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED]
>   GetCASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDEDByDocId(Int32)'.'.
>   See server logs for more details.

If i remove the         `public IQueryable<CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED> GetCASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDEDByDocId(int docId)` part - on updating service reference i get another error:

> The server encountered an error
>   processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'Internal Server Error. The
>   type
>   'CourtWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED'
>   is not a complex type or an entity
>   type.'.

**Environment**: Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added foreign keys and implemented LoadProperty. See the article from which i took this solution: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/the-cost-of-eager-loading-in-entity-framework/
Still if i have NO relations in database(for example i have no foreign keys)-i have another solution: create stored procedure and map it with import in your DB model. After that create complex type that will work in client too(tho you will have to access it by URI, not with lambda extensions). See example [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CC4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F121340%2FExposing-a-Stored-Procedure-in-WCF-Data-Service.aspx&ei=YNNsTfyhL4_Zsgbp3uXDBQ&usg=AFQjCNEGNGewyV0LdEUPmWwzphFaIi16rQ&sig2=yD6SfsVj5iKclJNwzXdDtw).
 Many thanks for other answerers in this thread, you have made me look deeper into the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data service is based on an Entity Framework model (the CEntities class is an ObjectContext).
If that's the case the types are completely read from the EF model (CSDL) and the class definitions are more or less ignored. So you need to define the type returned by your service operation in your EF model. Also note that for the IQueryable to work, that type has to be recognized by EF as an entity type (which might require mapping to the database, or something, EF experts will know more).

Answer (score -2):

For starters, WCF does not support IQueryable. That's your problem right there.

In your case IEnumerable should work.

You should look at a service as something that has methods and returns "data". This data could be single values, object instances or collections of objects. The client should not have to think about call a service to do a join, but rather, "give me the data for such and such - given these parameters".

You method name imparts the correct "intent" GetCaseStageHistoryExtendedByDocId(int docId), and what you get back is a collection of CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED objects. That's it.

An IQueryable implies something completely different and that concept does not pertain to a service as such.

**EDIT**

Try converting your Queryable to a List by calling the ToList() method on it.

return (from c in context.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY
                    join a in context.USRs on c.CREATOR_ID equals a.USRID
                    select new CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED()
                    {
                        CASE_STAGE_ID = c.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_ID,
                        CASE_STAGE_NAME = c.CASE_STAGE_NAME,
                        CREATE_DATE = c.CREATE_DATE,
                        CREATOR_ID = c.CREATOR_ID,
                        DOC_ID = c.DOC_ID,
                        LAST_VARIANT_DOCUMENT_ID = c.LAST_VARIANT_DOCUEMENT_ID,
                        CREATOR_FULLNAME = a.FULLNAME
                    }).ToList();

Note that you can only send serializable objects across to the client. So first make sure your objects are serializable.

Comment: The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED] GetCASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDEDByDocId(Int32)'.'.

Comment: Is your type serializable? Have you tested it to be serializable?

Comment: @nihi_l_ist, Try converting your query to a "List" by calling the ToList() method before returning.

Comment: @Shiv Kumar, ive added [Serializable] attribute to my class and changed return type of the method to List<>...Still: The exception message is 'Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED]' of method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CWcf.Code.CASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDED] GetCASE_STAGE_HISTORY_EXTENDEDByDocId(Int32)'.'.

Comment: I guess this problem is to do with dataContext? I't not really a WCF related issue but more to do with the object's you're using. Maybe the article at this link might help. http://samuelmueller.com/2009/11/working-with-projections-and-dtos-in-wcf-data-services/

Comment: Also make sure that you're actually getting the data before sending out to WCF. I think this issue basically says there is something wrong with you connection string. So anyway, write a test or test application and make sure you're getting a List of the required objects/data.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, i'll check all that.