# how to join two tables in linq? Using WCF Data Service

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I want to join two tables in one of my linq query. I have written one code but it gives me an error like below

```
The method 'Join' is not supported.
```

I have tried this code:

```
var query = (from ls in this.testEntities.abc
                     join itm in this.testEntities.edf on ls.ID equals itm.ID
                     where itm.val == param
                     select new
                     {
                       ls.Name,
                       ls.Contact
                     }).ToList();
```

Am I missing something?
If anyone have any idea about it than please help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do join operation on service side in WCF Data Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102141/how-to-do-join-operation-on-service-side-in-wcf-data-services)

Answer (score 1):

WCF Data Services is able to directly expand related objects based upon the Entity Data Model. (Don't worry about it if you don't know a lot about an EDM; it's not particularly important to the answer.) Since WCF Data Services is already aware, for instance, that a Product has a Category, I can fire up LinqPad, [give it this URL](http://services.odata.org/%28S%28readwrite%29%29/OData/OData.svc), and issue a query like the following:

```
Products.Expand("Category").Take(2)
```

The result is two products, each with a property of type Category.

I'm not really sure what that translates to in the other LINQ syntax, sorry.

HTH,
Mark